# update Current Item Database in Firebase with Angular / Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using firebase as a DB and Angular to create a backend.

I'm having some issue when I want to update one specific item of my database.

My DB is like this:

```
 --mydomain 
----posts 
--------POST LIST1 (crazy number and letter are display)
------------author 
------------imageDetails THIS IS WAHT SHOULD BE UPDATED)
------------etc 
--------POST LIST2 (crazy number and letter are display)
------------author 
------------imageDetails 
------------etc 
...
----users 
--------name 
--------email 
--------id
```

I'd like to be able to be able to update the table imageDetails of the CURRENT Item (posts)

But currently it do this when I try to update:

```
--mydomain 
----posts 
--------POST LIST1 (crazy number and letter are display)
------------author 
------------imageDetails 
------------etc 
--------POST LIST2 (crazy number and letter are display)
------------author 
------------imageDetails 
------------etc 
--------imageDetails(THIS IS WHERE ITS WRONG)
...
----users 
--------name 
--------email 
--------id
```

My original code was:

```
 var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('posts/');
```

I also try the following:

```
 var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + posts.key +'/test');
```

without success, I'm having 'posts is not defined'

The full code is like:

```
    app.controller('myController', ['$scope','$firebaseStorage',function($scope,     $firebaseStorage) {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");
// Create a Firebase Storage reference
  var storage = firebase.storage();
   var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + posts.key +'/test').push().key;


  var storageRef = storage.ref();
  var filesRef = storageRef.child('files');

  $scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
  console.log("Let's upload a file!");
  console.log($scope.file);
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(file.name).put(file);
  storageRef.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        }, function() {
            //handle error
        }, function() {
       //url of storage file 
            var downloadURL = storageRef .snapshot.downloadURL;
          firebaseRef.update({'url':downloadURL})
        // firebaseRef.update().ref().child('posts').child({'oui':downloadURL});
          // const dbref = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').child(uid);

     console.log(downloadURL);

        });
    };

 }]);
```

How can I achieve this? I've been trying to use push, but it doesn't change anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You seem to be using the Firebase Storage service to update values in your Firebase Database. That won't work. I recommend that you start from the top of the documentation (which covers the database before other features) here: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/guide/introduction-to-angularfire.md

Comment: don't use push,push will create unique id.but your problem is yo want update some id field.but my question how will you know which id you will update if you have multiple firebase id

Comment: im trying to updaate the current post id yes something like var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('posts' + currentpostid );
but i dont know how to

Comment: Franck, what is the process to do ? I can not figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope','$firebaseStorage',function($scope,     $firebaseStorage) {
    var ref = firebase.database.ref("posts");
// Create a Firebase Storage reference
  var storage = firebase.storage();



  var storageRef = storage.ref();
  var filesRef = storageRef.child('files');

  $scope.uploadFile = function(file,group) {
  console.log("Let's upload a file!");
  console.log($scope.file);
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(file.name).put(file);
  storageRef.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        }, function() {
            //handle error
        }, function() {
        var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('posts');
        var downloadURL = storageRef.snapshot.downloadURL;
            group.imageDetails = downloadURL;
            firebaseRef.child(group.title).update(group);
            console.log(downloadURL);


        });
    };

 }]);
```

Comment: hmm, in having a posts is not defined :/

Comment: check once@tibewww

Comment: still no luck :( :( :(